# no_top weights for keras models

Tags: deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

Pre-trained deep learning models have 2 types of weights associated with them,with top(meaning the dense fully connected layer) and without_top(removing the dense fully connected layer). I want to know how to train a model for the no_top weights

for eg: I have an architecture and I want to create weights for it trained on cifar10 data.So how to train for that?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about CIFAR10, I will give you an example for image classification.
First you get your pre-trained model from Keras without the top layers.

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
base_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(48, 48, 3))
```

Then you add your new layers for the classification tasks.

```
x = base_model.output
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(x)
prediction = Dense(10, activation='softmax', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(x)
```

The last layer has 10 units since CIFAR10 has 10 classes.

You create your model.

```
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=prediction)
```

You get the CIFAR10 data.

```
from keras.datasets import cifar10
(Xtrain, Ytrain), (Xtest, Ytest) = cifar10.load_data()

Ytrain = to_categorical(Ytrain)
Ytest = to_categorical(Ytest)
```

Compile and train.

```
model.compile(Adam(), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(Xtrain, Ytrain, batch_size=64, epochs=1, validation_data=(Xtest, Ytest))
```

**Note**: Here the training will change the weights of all your layers (pre-trained layers + new layers). You might want to freeze the pre-trained layers before training to keep their nicely trained weights.

Comment: My question is how to create that pre-trained model without top layers.